# Is it possible to export my data from Trello, to back it up?

Tags: backup, trello

Is there a way to export my data from Trello to my own computer?

I'm happy to accept any file format, so long as the data is in a file-format that can be parsed, e.g. I'm comfortable with writing a script to extract the data.

(I always try, with any online data I create, to find a way to export a copy of the data, and I have a Sunday evening routine of doing data dumps, then local backups.)

Comment: It would be great if we can export data not only as back-up but for stats monitoring purposes. ^^

Comment: Note: the Trello Dump works pretty well but broke https, suggest you logout and log back in once you use it.

Comment: For those who want a formatted version instead of raw JSON, here is a web app we made for ourselves: http://tianshuo.github.com/trello Feature requests and Bug reports go here: https://trello.com/board/trello2html/4fb10d0e312c2b226f1eb4a0

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With the release of the [Data Export feature](https://trello.com/c/RdSTH7no), you can now

1. Go to your board
2. Click the "Board Menu" button (on the right-hand-side of the screen)
3. Select "Share, Print, and Export"
4. Click "JSON"

This will download a copy of your board data.

Pro tips:

- You can also just add .json (or /somename.json) to the end of a board or card URL, to get the prompt to save the downloaded file  (e.g. https://trello.com/board/welcome-board/4e6a8095efa69909ba007382/somename.json)
- Alternatively, instead of clicking on the "JSON" button, you can right-click on it, and copy the URL
- If you have lots of boards that you want to download regularly, you'll have to save all the JSON links somewhere for all your boards, and download each one individually.
- Changing the names of all these individual files for each set of backups could get a little tedious, so one idea would be to create a new folder each time you backup your boards, and then save a set of exported files into that folder.

Comment: Absolutely awesome!!! Thanks very much indeed for this.

Comment: For those who want a formatted version instead of raw JSON, here is a web app we made for ourselves: http://tianshuo.github.com/trello Feature requests and Bug reports go here: https://trello.com/board/trello2html/4fb10d0e312c2b226f1eb4a0

Answer (score 14):

**Update:** This is now available from a print/share/export menu on board and card detail.

<del>Not currently. But it has been requested often and should be coming soon.</del>

<del>There is currently a card for this: https://trello.com/card/board/data-export/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e9d8a91f482dd34ea18335a</del>

Comment: Thanks. I looked for it on the [Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c), to vote for it, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @Clare I might try to whip up a javascript bookmarklet that does it. $(".list-card-title").text() gets you all the text from the card titles.

Comment: That would be fantastic. Yes please, and thank you. I've been looking for a reason to start learning JavaScript. This will be it.

Comment: Just wanted to add my support for creating some kind of backup option if it is being considered.

Comment: It's a must have feature.

Comment: There is currently a card for this: https://trello.com/card/board/data-export/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e9d8a91f482dd34ea18335a

Comment: This feature has been released

Answer (score 8):

As a stopgap, there's a (third party) XML export bookmarklet here:

http://bryanesmith.com/downloads/trello-dump/

**Note:** Using this bookmarklet can break HTTPS. You might want to logout and login again after using this tool.

Comment: Groovy script to parse the XML into a "pseudo csv": https://gist.github.com/1633027

Answer (score 6):

The following bookmarklet will only export an outline of your board; not nearly enough detail for a true export or backup, but it's a start. The script could be much more refined, but worked in IE9, FF 7, and Chrome against my own board and 3 others I tried.

```
javascript:
var l=document.getElementsByClassName('list');
var lp='';
for(x=0;x<l.length;x++){
    var ltc=l[x].getElementsByClassName('list-title');
    var lt=ltc[0].getElementsByTagName('h2');
    lp=lp+lt[0].innerHTML+'\n';
    var cards=l[x].getElementsByClassName('list-card-title');
    for(y=0;y<cards.length;y++){
        var cardTitle=cards[y].getElementsByTagName('a');
        lp=lp+'\t- '+cardTitle[0].innerHTML+'\n';
    }
}
var tad=document.createElement('div');
tad.innerHTML="<div align=\"right\">[<a href=\"#\"onClick=\"tad.style.visibility=\'hidden\'\;\">Close</a>]&nbsp<p/></div>&nbsp;Copy the text below into another editor for an outline of your board<p/>";
var ta=document.createElement('textarea');
ta.value=lp;
document.body.appendChild(tad);
tad.style.position="absolute";
tad.style.left='20%';
tad.style.top='20%';
tad.style.border='solid 2px black';
tad.style.backgroundColor='white';
tad.appendChild(ta);
ta.select();
void(0);
```

Comment: Wow - this is great. I was able to save the outline of 9 boards in a couple of minutes. Thanks very much indeed!

Answer (score 5):

Please see http://trello.com/privacy for the prospects for data migration and APIs.

Comment: Hi @Rich, You don't need to add that you are a member of the Trello team in every post. You should just add it to your User profile as per the [FAQ on signatures](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I've seen the Privacy/Portability statements before posting and there were just "prospects". That's why I was wondering if someone has found any go-around. Without any possibility to export data to Excel I cannot have any vantages using this great tool for my purposes... makes me frustrated.

Comment: Sorry for your frustration. Trello has been out for less than two months, so will be adding features fast.

Answer (score 4):

A card for data export has been added to the Trello Development board. It will likely be developed after the public API though.

https://trello.com/card/board/data-export/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e9d8a91f482dd34ea18335a

Comment: This feature has been released

Answer (score 2):

If you want an automated solution, I've created a Google Spreadsheet that auto imports your open Trello boards every 4 hours. It's not as complete as the Trello export function, but it gives you most things you'd want. Details here: 
http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/online-scrum-tools-part-4-trello-backup/

Answer (score 1):

Joel has just tweeted that there's now a similar bookmarklet to dump Trello data to XML: **[Trello Dump](http://bryanesmith.com/downloads/trello-dump/)**

Particular differences from [@BrettB's script here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18975/is-it-possible-to-export-my-data-from-trello-to-back-it-up/20808#20808):

1. It's presented as a button on a web page, that can be dragged to a browser toolbar, so it's a bit easier to set up
2. It downloads the colour tag of each item (but not the name of the tag)

Answer (score 0):

[as recommended by Trello](http://help.trello.com/article/924-making-sense-of-trellos-json-export)

1. Go to Board Menu > Share, Print, & Export (this will export the data to a JSON file)
2. Use this [JSON to CSV converter](https://json-csv.com) to convert the JSON file to CSV format.
3. You will then have the data stored inside a readable file (CSV).  This can then be opened up in Excel or Open Office.

[Also see here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/32108/how-do-i-export-data-to-excel)