# How do I get my data out of Trello?

Tags: trello, export, microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to export my data from Trello, to back it up?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18975/is-it-possible-to-export-my-data-from-trello-to-back-it-up)

Is there a way (or is it planned) to export Boards, Lists or specific cards to an external downloadable file of any kind? Preferably Excel Spreadsheets or something similar.

I would be able to have a kind of summary on an excel file so I can share this and manipulate information with any other apps involved in my projects management environment.

Comment: See also the answers on [Is it possible to export my data from Trello, to back it up?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18975/9027)