# Can Trello roll back to previous revisions of boards or cards?

Tags: trello

I'm considering using Trello to replace lists we keep in FogBugz wikis and in Google Docs. But both of those allow version control -- I can see what the list looked like yesterday, and roll back to that version if I need to.

Can Trello do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can now export your data from Trello - see [Is it possible to export my data from Trello, to back it up?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18975/is-it-possible-to-export-my-data-from-trello-to-back-it-up) - but there is no built in way to import historical data back in.

The [Trello FAQ](http://blog.trello.com/trello-common-questions/) makes no mention of importing even new data, and it says the API is read-only.