# Export Trello data to Excel

Tags: trello, migrate-data, microsoft-excel

I am using Trello as the Scrum tool of choice but need a way of exporting data to populate my burn down charts.

We are using Google Chrome but have data security concerns, so exporting to Excel is the preferred method at present.

How can I export Trello data to Excel?

Comment: If you're just looking for an efficient way to create charts, you can take a look at the Trello API at https://trello.com/docs/ or if you don't want to program your own service or app, you can check out Trello charting options from sites like http://www.chartbreeze.com or http://bluelinegamestudios.com/trello

Comment: http://blog-trapias.rhcloud.com/trelloexport-trello-to-excel/ a chrome extension that does the job

Comment: Not quite what you asked for, but you can just copy paste each column into Excel which takes but a minute if you only have a few columns and you want a one off export...

Comment: There's also an Excel 2016 add-in that will let you do it, explained here https://blog.extracts.io/how-import-trello-cards-into-excel-2016-dc04392ebd2d

Answer (score 5):

There is a free application known as TrelloExcel out there. I've been using it for about a week or two now - https://github.com/dillenmeister/TrelloExcel

It will very nicely export/import data, but it doesn't seem to handle updating existing items. For what you need it for, I think it will work to get you the task name, description, and due date (but no story points, hours or what is left). But then again, TrelloScrum adds the story points to the name in parentheses, so it couldn't be extremely difficult to extract it for your charts.

Comment: That's more of a comment, isn't?

Comment: Why would it be a comment? The OP asked if there was anything that would export to excel from Trello - I pointed to a possible solution.

Comment: The _"I'm looking at using this"_ triggered me a bit.

Comment: I used for about a week and I can say that it sort of fills the job. You can export and import records, but it doesn't seem to update.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit off topic because it doesn't answer the question of Excel exporting, but it does address the side of good solutions for burndown charts. We use Trello Burndown from Blue Line Game Studios. It does a pretty good job and everyone can update their piece so it's not dependent on sharing an excel spreadsheet. You can find that at http://bluelinegamestudios.com/trello

Another thing I've seen folks do is use Google Docs Spreadsheets to do the charting. There are several articles listed that walk through how to set that up. There is a good one at http://echobehind.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/create-your-own-burndown-chart-using-trello-api-and-google-apps-script/ and at http://luebken.com/?p=354

Answer (score 1):

There is no current functionality to do this (I'm not on the Beta, so I cannot test the Bulk Export functionality currently on offer, although it doesn't look like its what you need).

However, there is a card on the Ideas stack (sort of a feature request list), entitled [CSV or Other Export](https://trello.com/c/RdSTH7no). This looks like more what you want - however it's not implemented and is not on the list of items coming next. Looking at the comments on this card shows a workaround posted by "Zander Hill" which details how to use a Ruby Gem into XLSX (plus other formats). You may find joy in that solution, however I am unable to provide any support for this as I'm not a Ruby expert.

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Board Menu > Share, Print, & Export (this will export the data to a JSON file)
2. Use this [JSON to CSV](https://json-csv.com) converter to convert the JSON file to CSV format.
3. Open the file up in Excel.

As recommended by Trello:
http://help.trello.com/article/924-making-sense-of-trellos-json-export

Answer (score 1):

I have tested 2 tools allowing to export trello data to Excel:

Directly in Trello, you can subscribe to their Business Class package and export all cards from all boards in one operation. See their help page here. https://help.trello.com/article/747-exporting-data-from-trello-1

You can use the add-on [Bridge24 for Trello](https://bridge24.com?afmc=4q). That tool allow you to select exactly which boards and cards you want to export to Excel. It will export your cards (including custom fields), checklists, comments and documents to separate sheets.

Answer (score 0):

**Trello now has their own export capability built into Trello.**

You can access this from the menu on the right of your Trello Boards and export to CSV or JSON. For generating a burndown chart you could export daily and generate a count of the cards in your Sprint Backlog and In Progress lists. If you need to extract points data that should be possible if the points are in custom fields or with some regex to extract from Card titles (which is still a popular way for people to do it!)

The built in export feature requires you to be paying for your Trello subscription. There is an up to date write up of alternatives [Trello Exporting options here](https://www.bluecatreports.com/trello-reporting/exporting-trello-data/) which includes options which would work for free Trello accounts as well.